# passing string to file open function in python

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.x

I have a user input and I want to pass it as the file name parameter of the open function.  This is what I have tried:

```
filename = input("Enter the name of the file of grades: ")
file = open(filename, "r")
```

When the user input is `openMe.py` an error arises,

```
NameError: name 'openMe' is not defined
```

but when the user inputs `"openMe.py`" it works fine.  I am confused as to why this is the case because I thought the filename variable is a string.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `raw_input` in Python 2:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter the name of the file of grades: ")
```

`raw_input` returns a string while `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.

How does `eval("openMe.py")` works:

> Because python thinks that in `openMe.py`,  `openMe` is an object while
>   `py` is its attribute, so it searches for `openMe` first and if it is
>   not found then error is raised. If `openMe` was found then it searches 
>   this object for the attribute `py`.

Examples:

```
>>> eval("bar.x")  # stops at bar only
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined

>>> eval("dict.x")  # dict is found but not `x`
AttributeError: type object 'dict' has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: Why does eval("openMe.py") strip the .py?

Comment: @Sarien Because python thinks that in `openMe.py`,  `openMe` is an object while `py` is it's attribute, so it searches for `openMe` first and if it is not found then error is raised.

Answer (score 1):

As Ashwini said, you must use `raw_input` in python 2.x because `input` is taken as essentially `eval(raw_input())`.

The reason why `input("openMe.py")` appears to strip the `.py` at the end is because python attempts to find some object called `openMe` and access it's `.py` attribute.

```
>>> openMe = type('X',(object,),{})() #since you can't attach extra attributes to object instances.
>>> openMe.py = 42
>>> filename = input("Enter the name of the file of grades: ")
Enter the name of the file of grades: openMe.py
>>> filename
42
>>>
```